# Bootstrap v5.1.3: merge $colors with $theme-colors map

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to add some **color variables** such as **"blue"**, **"indigo"** ... to `$theme-colors` map it's work but after compiling it shows duplicated in `:root` selector like the image below.

**Here is the result:**

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjmoc.png)

this is my **_variables.scss** file:

```
// Import functions
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";

$white: #fff;
$gray-100: #f8f9fa;
$gray-200: #e9ecef;
$gray-300: #dee2e6;
$gray-400: #ced4da;
$gray-500: #adb5bd;
$gray-600: #6c757d;
$gray-700: #495057;
$gray-800: #343a40;
$gray-900: #212529;
$black: #000;

$blue: #0d6efd;
$indigo: #6610f2;
$purple: #6f42c1;
$pink: #d63384;
$red: #dc3545;
$orange: #fd7e14;
$yellow: #ffc107;
$green: #198754;
$teal: #20c997;
$cyan: #0dcaf0;

$primary: #c55e0a;
$secondary: $gray-600;
$success: $green;
$info: $cyan;
$warning: $yellow;
$danger: $red;
$light: $gray-100;
$dark: $gray-900;

$theme-colors: (
    "primary": $primary,
    "secondary": $secondary,
    "success": $success,
    "info": $info,
    "warning": $warning,
    "danger": $danger,
    "light": $light,
    "dark": $dark
);

$custom-theme-colors: (
    "blue": $blue,
    "indigo": $blue,
    "purple": $blue,
    "pink": $blue,
    "yellow": $blue,
    "teal": $teal
);

$theme-colors: map-merge($theme-colors, $custom-theme-colors);

// Import required Bootstrap stylesheets
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities";

@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

**How I can fix this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can [read in the Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/customize/sass/), customizations should be kept in a separate file. Therefore, you shouldn't modify `_variables.scss` but instead create seperate file with your custom colors.

The custom file portion would [look like this](https://codeply.com/p/5vRQcV0I06)

ex: custom.scss

```
@import "bootstrap/functions";
@import "bootstrap/variables";

$custom-colors: (
    "blue": $blue,
    "indigo": $indigo,
    "purple": $purple,
    "pink": $pink,
    "yellow": $yellow,
    "teal": $teal
);

$theme-colors: map-merge($theme-colors, $custom-colors);
      
@import "bootstrap";
```

Also, it's expected that the :root variables would appear twice since you're merging them with the theme-colors map. Take a look at how the :root gets built in `_root.scss`...

First the $colors map is iterated.. then the $theme-colors map is iterated so it would make perfect since you're seeing --bs-blue, --bs-indigo, etc... twice in the :root...

```
 @each $color, $value in $colors {
    --#{$variable-prefix}#{$color}: #{$value};
  }

  ....

  @each $color, $value in $theme-colors {
    --#{$variable-prefix}#{$color}: #{$value};
  }
```

There is nothing to fix, it's working as expected. Maybe if you can describe what you're trying to achieve instead of describing a symptom there would be a different answer or better solution.